# PHP String help required

Tags: php

I need to call the following parameters on a string

```
control_lbsresulted.php?lat=-25.74546&long=28.11222&dist=300&msisdn=0831231234
```

I have this string currently

```
<a href="control_lbsresulted.php?msisdn=<? echo $rows['msisdn']; ?>" class="update">Look Up</a>
```

I can only seem to get the above to draw the MSISDN for me, do i need to add semi-colon with spacing to get the other as required as such:

```
<a href="control_lbsresulted.php?msisdn=<? echo $rows['msisdn']; ?> , dist=<? echo $rows['dist']; ?>" class="update">Look Up</a>
```

Comment: You need `&` but you put ` , `. Why? link is just text, so you need to write what you see.

Comment: What do you want all those to be passed as a query string?

Comment: Thanks everyone's gave work I just voted one i used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just try below:

```
<a href="control_lbsresulted.php?lat=<? echo $rows['lat']; ?>&long=<? echo $rows['long']; ?>&dist=<? echo $rows['dist']; ?>&msisdn=<? echo $rows['msisdn']; ?>" class="update">Look Up</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you need to separate them with an ampersand (&) as you described in the first line. It would look something like:

```
<a href="control_lbsresulted.php?msisdn=<? echo $rows['msisdn']; ?>&dist=<? echo $rows['dist']; ?>" class="update">Look Up</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<a href="control_lbsresulted.php?lat=-25.74546&long=28.11222&dist=<? echo $rows['dist']; ?>&msisdn=<?php echo $rows['msisdn']; ?>" class="update">Look Up</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="control_lbsresulted.php?msisdn=<? echo $rows['msisdn']; ?>&dist=<? echo $rows['dist']; ?>" class="update">Look Up</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate the string with ampersand no with coma's.
you try this way-

```
<a href="control_lbsresulted.php?msisdn=<? echo $rows['msisdn'];?>&dist=<? echo $rows['dist'];?>" class ="update">Look Up</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You first variable goes behind the "?", the others are seperated by an ampersand "&"

```
 <a href="control_lbsresulted.php?lat=<?php echo $rows['lat'] ?>&long=<?php echo $rows['long'] ?>&dist=<?php echo $rows['dist']; ?>&msisdn=<?php echo $rows['msisdn']; ?>" class="update">Look Up</a>
```

Oh, and it is recommended to use the long tags:

Answer (score 0):

use & separate parameters. like this

```
<a href="control_lbsresulted.php?msisdn=<? echo $rows['msisdn']; ?>&paramter2=<?=$row['param']?>" class="update">Look Up</a>
```